# Shiny app gets disconnected from the server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

Shiny app works fine locally but gets disconnected from the server with following error:
[image]

I have installed and loaded the library rgdal, but still keep on getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing when it works locally you're running it on windows?

What does `ld /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rgdal/libs/rgdal.so` return?

The error message is telling you that a shared object that the rgdal needs is missing.
This object should have been linked at install time and the install should have failed if it didn't exist (assuming it was installed through R).

At a guess, I'd say you're missing a system dependency, which is something like libgdal-dev or libgdal-devel, depending on your distro.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error, it looks like you may not have uploaded your data files when you uploaded your app to shiny. Click File > Publish and make sure all of the files, including your app.R (and/or ui & server files) AND your data files are selected.

Or, do you setwd() at the beginning of your code? If so, delete that line and try again.